# can I call a PHP method to run asynchronously?

Tags: php, jquery

When a user views a certain profile page I need to send the end user an email but would like to do this asynchronously if at all possible.  Can this be done with PHP? I really don't want to wait for the PHP function to complete before rendering the rest of the page.  It should be seamless to the user.

Or is this a better solution from the client side:

```
$.post("msg.php?user=xxx", function(data) {
    ....   
}, "json");
```

Is there a preferred method?

Comment: Depending on server architecture, there's also a plethora of MQ systems and Gearman that might be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want interactivity, go for the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method; if you just want to hit a listener script (and thereby initialize a set piece of PHP functionality), use [`post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) which is a short-hand version of the same method:

```
$(function() {

   // If you just want to activate a listener script (with no interaction)
   $.post('/path/to/script.php');

   // If you want to receive data back from your script for use in the DOM
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/path/to/script.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
   }).done(function( response ) {
      alert( response );
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have your page perform asynchronous actions is to use AJAX, as you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a script with proc_open or shell_exec if you're stuck with a server side solution. There may be some restrictions on this depending on your environment, but this is generally a quick and dirty way to multi-thread PHP and thus allow for things to happen asynchronously.

That is, somewhere in the script, if a flag is set (such as a notify flag) it will dispatch a process like '../private/notify.php' ... see how to pass arguments to a command line call of php.  There is also the option of calling sendmail directly.

Make sure you test it out a bit before trying it; you need to make sure that:

1. You can safely and successfully spawn the new thread
2. You do not need to wait for that thread to complete to finish the current script execution
3. That thread will safely finish and exit on its own, whether with errors or successful
4. There is a way to handle errors (such as mail failing) so that you can debug problems. A logfile might be the best answer here.